# IntentService to collect users location in the background on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, service, background, location

My android app has location permissions, what I want to do is create a service (maybe intent service) that will be launched in the background every time other app uses the GPS and collect the current location into my app sqlite db (until the user decides to turn off the GPS or exists the app that uses the GPS)

Is that even possible? if it is possible:

1) how would this intent service look like?
2) how do I configure it in my appmanifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that even possible?

Not directly. You have no way of knowing if "other app uses the GPS".

You are welcome to register for location updates from [the `PASSIVE_PROVIDER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER), which may fit your needs.